# I have an error in Twincat HMI Desktop.view part

Tags: twincat, twincat-hmi

I am creating a Twincat HMI project. I have a file called Desktop.view. This file has HTML codes and the ability to open in the Designer section in Twincat. When I take the project live, the HTML codes in my Desktop.view file are displayed in the Web Browser without any problems. But this Desktop.view file is not displayed in my Twincat project. Only a blank white page appears (in the Designer section). Has anyone encountered this error? If so, I would be very grateful if you contact me here or via email.

I am trying to create a Twincat HMI Project.

Answer (score 0):

You can press 《》 sign to see the code behind your view file
Also if doesnt load the view properly in designer

Right click on designer press reload option

Sometimes reopening twincat cure this issue as well

Comment: I will try this. But if this doesn't work, I rewrite here. Thanks

Comment: Odds are you will need to find the error in code. Designer had a lot of bugs when I ised it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the error was related to my computer. I installed an older version and the error was resolved. At the same time, the version I was trying to install on my computer did not have Embedded Browser installed. I downloaded the old version and downloaded the Embedded Browser as an extra and the error was solved. I can use it now.